# iOS: Resize CMSampleBufferRef directly?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, avcapturesession

I am getting CMSampleBufferRef buffers from an AVCaptureSession/AVCaptureVideoDataOutput on iOS 4. Can I resize these directly (without conversion)?

I don't always need a full resolution feed and I'm looking for a performance bump. Switching sessionPreset is too slow, as is using full AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh buffers all the time.

Thanks.